# form instance is not shown

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

views.py

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def date_format(request):
    save_msg = ''
    user = request.user
    try:
        settings = Settings.objects.get(user=user.id)
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings)
    except:
        settings = None
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(initial={'date_format':0, 'time_format':0})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(request.POST, instance=settings)
        if settingsForm.is_valid():
            settings = settingsForm.save(commit=False)
            settings.user = user
            settings.save()
            save_msg = 'Date format has been updated.'
    return render(request,'setting/date_format.html',
                           {
                            'about_menu': True,
                            'date_tab':True,
                            'SettingsForm':settingsForm,
                            'save_msg': save_msg,
                           })
```

models.py

```
class Settings(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    date_format = models.BooleanField('Date format', default=False)
    time_format = models.BooleanField('Time format', default=False)
    is_contactlist_active = models.BooleanField('Contacts', default=True)
```

For initial value the default format is shown. But if I save that value to database the values are saving but the selected format(form instance) is not shown.

Comment: are you sure this view code works ?

Comment: yes,it is saving the values problem is,form is not holding the values,always showing the empty form

Comment: you still use that old render_to_response?, render shortcut seem cleaner.

Comment: @christophe31,replaced with "render" problem is still their.

Comment: My guess is, your code is touching the `except` block, and then `settingsForm = SettingsForm(request.POST, instance=settings)` evaluates to `settingsForm = SettingsForm(request.POST, instance=None)`, hence the issue. Also, looks like your view needs a `login_required` decorator

Comment: @karthikr,@login_required decorator i added in my code but not mentioned here.Is any alternative way is their to make it work.

Comment: try the code in the answer. Basically, reinitialize the settings form

Comment: @user2086641 it was not an answer, just a suggestion, or a comment. For me to have better answers, you need to simplify you view until you identify your problem. Do you insure each user can't have more than One setting (by using a OneToOneField) If yes why don't you use related name instead of requesting Setting table? # this is still not meant to answer your question, more to say what I think can be done better in your code #

Comment: @limelights,do you have any answer to this question.

Comment: You shouldn't use a catch-all `except` like that, you should change it to `except Settings.DoesNotExist`

Comment: What are your models?

Comment: @Rohan,models updated in Question.

Comment: @user2086641, I suspect you are getting `MultipleObjectsReturned:` or some other exception by `Settings.objects.get(user=user.id)`. As you have `ForeignKey` on `User` there can be multiple `Settings` for an user.

Comment: @Rohan If that is the case,how to handle it in my views.

Comment: Is any other alternative solution for this issue.

Comment: what if you remove the `try` and the whole `except` block, do you get any error? We can try to help with that information

Comment: @HieuNguyen 1st error.local variable 'settingsForm' referenced before assignment.I initialized an empty form,so it got solved.  2nd error.Since i set default value in form widget,the default value comes to display and if i hit save,i got this error "local variable 'settings' referenced before assignment" in line 13. 3rd If i remove the settings from form instance and hit save,it is saving the data,but form instantiation is not happening

Comment: Are you sure your user has any settings? You've improved your code but still, see me reply below. At least try  settings = _retrieve_user_settings() and then print it out to check that you have the good information...

Comment: Also if you comment all your code and just do: settingsForm = SettingsForm(initial={'date_format':0, 'time_format':0}) does that actually work?

Comment: @François,comment all code means,in try ,catch block know.

Comment: @François,i commented settingsForm = SettingsForm(initial={'date_format':0, 'time_format':0}) and tried,i got the error as settings referenced before assignment,i removed settings from form and tried ,it is showing the initial value and saving the values in database,so for every save a new row of values is saved against user.

Comment: @François,i tried your pattern,form field is not rendered,even i changed the name of the form in forms.py and views.

Comment: I think,it is returning multiple user because if i am trying without instance,it is saving and creating data format morethan one time for the same user id.In normal if this is the case,if we redirect to date_format.html,it should show error like "more than one argument for user it takes one",instead it is showing the empty form.

Comment: Could you show your code AND TESTs when you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is hard to follow to be honest - and would be hard to test. Start by splitting it with empty functions:

```
def date_format(request):
    settings = _retrieve_user_settings() # see below
    form = _prepare_settings_form(settings) # see below

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = _prepare_settings_form(settings, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            _save_settings(form) # see below
            save_msg = 'Date format has been updated.'

     return render(request,'setting/date_format.html',
                           {
                            ...
                           }
      )


def _retrieve_user_settings()
    """
    get the logged-in user settings or None if the user is logged off or doesn't have any settings
    """
    pass

def _prepare_settings_form(settingsInstance=None, data=None)
    """
    prepare the form with the settings provided
    use default values if the settings are empty (to pre-fill the form)
    """
    pass

def _save_settings(form) # this one is even better out of the view
    # throw exception if the form wasn't validated
    # retrieve the user for the new settings
    # save the settings (attached to the user)
    pass
```

Before jumping into implementing the code for these 3 new small functions, write their unit tests and you'll be sure to end with a nice working code. If you think that's too much effort, look at the size of this StackOverflow thread and therefore the number of manual tests you've been doing ;)

That's just an example, you can split your code differently - but you should really avoid long views and long code in a try statement...

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the "current answer" looks like, since it's been removed, but I can try suggesting you few things:

```
...
user = request.user
try:
    settings_inst = Settings.objects.get(user=user.id)
    settings_init = None
    settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings_inst)
except:
    settings_init = {'date_format':0, 'time_format':0}
    settings_inst = None
    settingsForm = SettingsForm(initial=settings_init)

if request.method == 'POST':

    ## if settings_inst is None, you should fallback using the initial settings dict ##
    if settings_inst:
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(request.POST, instance=settings_inst)
    else:
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(request.POST, initial=settings_init)

    if settingsForm.is_valid():
        ...
```

In your case, if you use `settings = None` it will override the data you pass with `initial` before you check if a POST request happened, making you loose every time your `{'date_format' ...}` initial dict.

NB: I renamed settings into `settings_inst` and `settings_init` just to make it easier to explain to you (and to see what's going on, from your point of view). Of course rearrange the code as it best fits your needs (aka: I don't kwnow if this can break other stuff in your code or not.)

Comment: well don't copy and paste the code out of SO and expect it to work, that's the first rule. I'm editing btw, maybe it's better.

Comment: No Samuele,the issue is not solved.form Instantiation is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are getting `MultipleObjectsReturned` or some other exception by `Settings.objects.get(user=user.id)`.

As you have `ForeignKey` on User there can be multiple `Settings` for an user

You can change your view as

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def date_format(request):
    save_msg = ''
    user = request.user
    try:
        #to update latest settings for an user
        settings = Settings.objects.filter(user=user.id).latest('id')
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings)
    except:
        settings = None
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(initial={'date_format':0, 'time_format':0})
    if request.method == 'POST':
    #your existing code
    ...
```

---

Or If you want to only one settings for each user use `OneToOne` relationship as

```
class Settings(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)
    ....
```

Then you can refer it in view as `request.user.settings` directly. And update view as

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def date_format(request):
    save_msg = ''
    user = request.user
    if request.user.settings:
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=request.user.settings)
    else:
        settings = None
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(initial={'date_format':0, 'time_format':0})
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
```

Comment: I tried with this approach,if i use latest('id'),for every form post a new row of data is added,so the form is empty and it is showing the initial value in form.Form Instantiation is not happening

Answer (score 0):

I'm combining several solutions from others, please try:

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def date_format(request):
    save_msg = ''
    user = request.user
    try:
        settings_instance = Settings.objects.filter(user=user.id).latest('id')
        settings_initial = None
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings_instance)
    except Settings.DoesNotExist:
        settings_instance = None
        settings_initial = {'date_format':0, 'time_format':0}
        settingsForm = SettingsForm(initial=settings_initial)

    print settings_instance  # DEBUG here

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if settings_instance:   
            settingsForm = SettingsForm(request.POST, instance=settings_instance)
        else:
            settingsForm = SettingsForm(request.POST, initial=settings_initial)

        if settingsForm.is_valid():
            settings = settingsForm.save(commit=False)
            settings.user = user
            settings.save()
            save_msg = 'Date format has been updated.'

    return render(request, 'setting/date_format.html', {
        'about_menu': True,
        'date_tab':True,
        'SettingsForm':settingsForm,
        'save_msg': save_msg,
    })
```

If it doesn't work, please continue to debug at the point I specified.